# Track the traffic of an external website/ of an image being loaded on an external website

Tags: php, html, url

EDIT:

I want to count how many times a web page loads and every time it does load, I want to update an image (which is a jpg file) to display the number of times the page has been loaded. I know how to update the image and convert it into a jpg, but what I want to figure out is how to 'listen' to a page loading. This page is external to my servers...I have no access to it...just a random webpage.

What method should I use?

This is what I am hoping for:

```
<?php
   if (webpagevisited('www.stackoverflow.com')) //this would be the function
       {
         increase_hit_counter_by_one();
       }
```

I have created the function increase_hit_counter_by_one(). It uses a mySQL database to update the value and to filter duplicate IP addresses. What method would be best to create the webpagevisiited() function ?

Comment: What you show looks like a reasonable start. What one would usually do is save the count in a text file, or a database. There are tutorials for both ways

Comment: Oh I'm very familiar with all that, and filtering IP addresses etc etc...I simply omitted any unimportant code from my excerpt for friendlier readability :D

Comment: As @Pekka웃 wrote, all your problem should already be solved. It is probably more a problem how you search for a solution your own. Like in your question you are making many words to describe something simple. It is very likely you only need to improve your research and that is all. It is hard to help you with that on this website though. Stackoverflow is better suited for concrete programming problems.

Comment: Ah - in that case, I'm not really clear what your question is? If it's about how to identify the remote site, either put some info in the query string: `<img src="http://yourdomain.com/image.php?site=mysite">` or use the referrer, as suggested by dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - After you edited your answer and commented, you could use a simple .htaccess (i presume you are using apache with mod rewrite enabled) rewrite to modify the URL.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^image_counter.jpg$ image.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Assuming the .htaccess is in the root web directory along with your image.php script, now you can use `<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/image_conter.jpg" alt="" />` and the htaccess should rewrite the url to your script. Check the apache website for more information on htaccess rules.

Using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` you can then test against a specific URL you are counting.

And finally serve the image as required, eg.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); //or other correct mime type
//output image you created
```

---

You would need to store the 'count' in a database or similar storage option to be able to persist the count variable, it would be reset every time the page loads as Dom rightly points out.

What I would recommend as the simplest option is to have your image src as your php file, eg.

```
<img src="image.php" alt="Hit Counter" />
```

Then in your image.php file you can retrieve your stored count, perhaps using Mysql, and increment it by one and save the new count. Then you can present your count in your image as you like.

Something like this for example:

```
<?php
//get saved count here as $count
$count++;
//save new count
//create image using count and present it.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)     I am familiar with that...I realise now that I may have asked my question in a very difficult to understand manner..I want to simply keep the image as a jpg file so that any other person on any webpage can use the  image. I want to track when the image is used and where it is used, without the person using the image needing to use any scripts or .php files.

Comment: I modified the answer according to your updated question and comment. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this seems closest to answering the question. I'll do some further research into the commands you've mentioned.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you get stuck I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be `$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`.

This should show you what webpage loaded the image, but can also be spoofed very easily via CURL or even false headers.

Also, the count would not be stored on that page as `$count` will be reset every time the image is loaded.

You will need a database of some sort to store/update the hits.